# Ubuntu: How to share data on Dual Boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, server, 20.04, windows, docker

I have Wİndows 10 installed on my PC and want to install Ubuntu Desktop. As I Software Developer, I think I should install all the Developer Tools to Ubuntu and make the necessary settings as I did on Windows.

However, there are some apps which has data used for development purpose e.g. a test database on Docker and another database on SQL Server. For this reason I think I also need to install Docker and SQL Server to Ubuntu as I did on Windows, **but** I think there is no need to create a separate database and I should use the same data files, containers on Windows. Is this a good approach?

Another issues is that, how can I use the same data files and containers on Ubuntu? I can access Windows drives from Ubuntu, but not have an idea how should I share data between these 2 operating systems. Any idea?

Comment: I use a common NTFS partition for my needs, but I don't have the same needs as you do.